# Parsing malformed JSON using Shell / Python

Tags: python, json, shell, parsing, flatten

I am trying to parse & flatten a JSON like file which appears like this:

```json
EventTime_t                : 2021-07-23T23:03:41.711Z
FileName_s                   : \\nb009\dfsroot\admin\usershares\klein\documents\importing ee data v5.0.pdf
FileAttributes_s : [
                                 {
                                   "Access": 70,
                                   "Count": 3,
                                   "FileType": "99c07caa-8fc4-4f94-b313-cb434493f900",
                                   "UniqueCount": null,
                                   "Attachment": null,
                                   "Name": "Employee Details - U.S."
                                 },
                                 {
                                   "Access": 93,
                                   "Count": 11,
                                   "FileType": "a44669fe-0d48-453d-a9b1-2cc83f2cba77",
                                   "UniqueCount": null,
                                   "Attachment": null,
                                   "Name": "Portable stack (BS)"
                                 }
                               ]
FileUpdatedBy_s             : 
FileUpdatedDate_t           : 2009-05-27T20:01:22Z

EventTime_t                : 2021-07-23T23:04:03.862Z
FileName_s                   : \\xdev1900.org\dfsroot\admin\usershares\klein\axn980\test management\bare cards to link.xlsx
FileAttributes_s : [
                                 {
                                   "Access": 85,
                                   "Count": 20,
                                   "FileType": "50842eb7-edc8-4019-85dd-5a5c1f2bb085",
                                   "UniqueCount": null,
                                   "Attachment": null,
                                   "Name": Plan Growth Number"
                                 }
                               ]
FileUpdatedBy_s             : Mike
FileUpdatedDate_t           : 1980-01-02T00:00:00Z
```

I wrote a bash script but I am not happy the way I wrote it.

```shell
#!/bin/bash

echo -n | tee col_1.txt col_2.txt col_3.txt col_4.txt col_5.txt col_6.txt col_7.txt col_8.txt col_9.txt col_10.txt 

cat full.json | grep '\"Access\"' | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/\"Access\"/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_1.txt
cat full.json | grep '\"Count\"' | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/\"Count\"/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_2.txt
cat full.json | grep '\"FileType\"' | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/\"FileType\"/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_3.txt
cat full.json | grep '\"UniqueCount\"' | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/\"UniqueCount\"/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_4.txt
cat full.json | grep '\"Attachment\"' | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/\"Attachment\"/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_5.txt
cat full.json | grep '\"Name\"' | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/\"Name\"/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_6.txt
 
paste -d ',' col_1.txt col_2.txt col_3.txt col_4.txt col_5.txt col_6.txt | pr -t -e20 > output1.txt
sed -i 's/"  *"/" "/g' output1.txt
sed -i 's/  */ /g' output1.txt

cat full.json | grep "EventTime_t" | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/EventTime_t/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_1.txt
cat full.json | grep "FileAttributes_s" | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/FileAttributes_s/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_2.txt
cat full.json | grep "FileUpdatedBy_s" | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/FileUpdatedBy_s/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_3.txt
cat full.json | grep "FileUpdatedDate_t" | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/:/\n/g' | awk '!(/FileUpdatedDate_t/ && seen[$0]++)' > col_4.txt

paste -d ',' col_6.txt col_7.txt col_8.txt col_9.txt | pr -t -e20 > output2.txt
sed -i 's/"  *"/" "/g' output2.txt
sed -i 's/  */ /g' output2.txt

ln=( $(grep -n "EventTime_t" full.json | cut -d ':' -f 1) )
last_line=`wc -l full.json | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
ln+=(${last_line})

cat /dev/null > fnl_output.csv
echo "1|" > col_10.txt
j=1;i=0;
while [ $i -lt ${#ln[*]} ];
do
  if [ -z ${ln[$j]} ]; then
      paste col_10.txt output2.txt | pr -t -e20 > output3.txt
      sed -e 's/" *"/ /g' -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/null//g' output3.txt | awk '!seen[$0]++' > output2.txt
      echo  -n | tee output3.txt
      while read line
      do
         count=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f 1`
         txt=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f 2`
         i=0
         while  [ $i -lt $count ]; do
            echo $txt >> output3.txt
            i=$(( $i + 1));
         done;
     done < output2.txt;
     paste -d ',' output3.txt output1.txt > fnl_output.csv

     rm -f ./*.txt
     exit 0;
   else
      if [ ${ln[$i]} -lt ${ln[$j]} ]; then
         start=${ln[$i]};
         end=`expr ${ln[$j]} - 1`;
         sed -n "${start},${end}p" full.json > ${start}.txt
         ln1=( $(grep -n '\"Access\"' ${start}.txt | cut -d ':' -f 1))
         t=`echo ${#ln1[*]}`
         echo $t"|" >> col_10.txt
         j=$(( $j + 1));
     fi
     i=$(( $i + 1));
  fi
done;
```

I know this is a lame way of parsing JSON for n number of reasons - going by key-value pairs by formatting each key, may not handle larger JSON files, creates lot of temporary files, etc.

And this JSON could have more additional attributes to be parsed - hence each time I find a new attribute - I must go back to the code and update.

Output of this shell script should be a set of rows and columns in csv format.

Can any one help me achieving the same in python?
(I tried the same in python using packages - 'json' and 'pandas', but they wont recognize this data as proper JSON)
*Note: Currently, Input files are nearly 50 to 100 MB in size. This size may grow in future.*

Thanks
Lakshminarasu Chenduri

Comment: It's not "a malformed JSON file", it's just a non-JSON format.

Comment: That said, "how do I write a parser for data roughly matching this example?" is very much too broad to be on-topic here. "How do I write a parser?" is typically a 300-level computer science course (often, the first half of an introductory class on compiler design). Describing how to do it _well_ is a topic for a book. Describing how to do it _badly_... well, why would anyone teach that?

Comment: On the other hand... you _do_ have actual JSON data embedded. If you can pick apart the values from the keys, then you can use a _real_ JSON parser for the subset of the values that are in fact JSON.

Comment: Part of that json data might also be broken. Just added an attempt to fix THAT string.

Answer (score 0):

As it is, that "json" could be "fixed" using sed

```
fixedInner=$(
    sed -re '
    s/\\/\\\\/g # escape
    s/^([^ :["]+) +: +"?(.{2,}|$)"?/"\1" : "\2",/ # double quote keys and values
    s/^([^ :["]+)( +): \[$/"\1"\2: [/ # double quote keys followed by [
    s/"EventTime_t.*/{\0/; s/("FileUpdatedDate_t.*),/\1},/ # add braces to object start and end
    # add , for alone ]
    s/ +[]] *$/],/ ' test.txt)
echo "[ ${fixedInner%?} ]" | jq -r '.'
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "EventTime_t": "2021-07-23T23:03:41.711Z",
    "FileName_s": "\\\\nb009\\dfsroot\\admin\\usershares\\klein\\documents\\importing ee data v5.0.pdf",
    "FileAttributes_s": [
      {
        "Access": 70,
        "Count": 3,
        "FileType": "99c07caa-8fc4-4f94-b313-cb434493f900",
        "UniqueCount": null,
        "Attachment": null,
        "Name": "Employee Details - U.S."
      },
      {
        "Access": 93,
        "Count": 11,
        "FileType": "a44669fe-0d48-453d-a9b1-2cc83f2cba77",
        "UniqueCount": null,
        "Attachment": null,
        "Name": "Portable stack (BS)"
      }
    ],
    "FileUpdatedBy_s": "",
    "FileUpdatedDate_t": "2009-05-27T20:01:22Z"
  },
  {
    "EventTime_t": "2021-07-23T23:04:03.862Z",
    "FileName_s": "\\\\xdev1900.org\\dfsroot\\admin\\usershares\\klein\\axn980\\test management\\bare cards to link.xlsx",
    "FileAttributes_s": [
      {
        "Access": 85,
        "Count": 20,
        "FileType": "50842eb7-edc8-4019-85dd-5a5c1f2bb085",
        "UniqueCount": null,
        "Attachment": null,
        "Name": "Plan Growth Number"
      }
    ],
    "FileUpdatedBy_s": "Mike",
    "FileUpdatedDate_t": "1980-01-02T00:00:00Z"
  },
  {}
]
```

I leave up to you to fix this case :-)
        `"Name": Plan Growth Number"`

Answer (score 0):

You need some customized parsing code. For example, we could first separate each event in the data and then process each field.

```py
STRING = "string"
LIST = "list"

FIELD_TYPE_MAPPING = {
    "EventTime_t" : STRING,
    "FileName_s" : STRING,
    "FileAttributes_s" : LIST,
    "FileUpdatedBy_s": STRING,
    "FileUpdatedDate_t": STRING

}

def process(data, fieldTypeMapping):
    output = {}
    mode = STRING
    linesOfList = []
    savedFieldName = None


    for line in data:
        # If we have : in a line, we may be starting a new field
        if ':' in line:
            components = line.split(':')
            fieldName = components[0].strip()

            if fieldName in fieldTypeMapping:
                if mode == LIST:
                    # Process the collected lines in the list field. (Here we just merge them into one line.)
                    # We should have something like output[savedFiledName] = handleDataForListField(linesOfList)
                    output[savedFieldName] = "".join(linesOfList)

                fieldType = fieldTypeMapping[fieldName]

                if fieldType == STRING:
                    # We could have a customized handling function based on the field name here
                    output[fieldName] = line[len(components[0]) + 1 :]
                    mode = STRING
                elif fieldType == LIST:
                    mode = LIST
                    linesOfList = []
                    savedFieldName = fieldName


        if mode == LIST:
            linesOfList.append(line) # we could process the line here

    return output


# Main Part
isInProgress = False
startPattern = 'EventTime_t'
endPattern = 'FileUpdatedDate_t'

# Process line by line
data = []
events = []

# Assume we process the data line by line
for line in input.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith(startPattern):
        isInProgress = True

    if isInProgress:
        data.append(line)

    if line.startswith(endPattern):
        isInProgress = False
        events.append(process(data, FIELD_TYPE_MAPPING))

# Testing Part
for item in events:
    print(item)
```